# (How) can I create or join a custom chat channel?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm fond of custom chat channels. I use them a lot in online games where people are often online, but not always playing together. As with most games, it *appears* that, the `/join` command works in D III, except for the fact that any of the channel names I try throw an error that the channel "doesn't exist." (I tested with some established names that I expected someone to have created. I also tried some alternate syntax like `/join <channelname>` with little success. The help displayed from the `/?` command provides the various channel join and quit commands, but none for creation. In other Blizzard games, trying to join a nonexistent channel created it automatically, but that doesn't seem to be the case here. How do I get into a chat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, there's no way to create a custom chat channel in Diablo III [and probably there will never be](http://diablo.incgamers.com/blog/comments/d3s-chat-channels-problems-and-solutions). Unless there's a big change, driven by players' rage, I don't think they're going to change their mind.

Comment: I don't know that I'd say 'will never be' based on that article. `Most people that want chat channels though are referring to guild channels, or otherwise channels they themselves can operate and choose to invite others to, and we see those as completely valid forms of chat (there’s a social structure backing the channel).` Sounds like exactly what I'm after to me.